# Dokuwiki on Raspbian “wheezy” (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, dokuwiki

I've installed the dokuwiki via apt-get. The first call to `http://localhost/dokuwiki` give me "403 Forbidden" as response:

```
Achtung! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /dokuwiki on this server.
```

In the log filee (/var/log/apache2/error.log) i found following:

```
client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/dokuwiki/
```

I don't have an idea, what is really wrong. So i've tried this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/share/dokuwiki
sudo chown -R www-data:root /usr/share/dokuwiki
```

but the problem was not solved. Any ideas?

**edit**:

https.conf is empty, here the output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mai  2 21:11 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and the  /usr/share/dokuwiki/.htaccess looks good (imho):

```
## Enable this to restrict editing to logged in users only

## You should disable Indexes and MultiViews either here or in the
## global config. Symlinks maybe needed for URL rewriting.
#Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

## make sure nobody gets the htaccess, README, COPYING or VERSION files
<Files ~ "^([\._]ht|README$|VERSION$|COPYING$)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>

## Uncomment these rules if you want to have nice URLs using
## $conf['userewrite'] = 1 - not needed for rewrite mode 2
#RewriteEngine on
#
## Not all installations will require the following line.  If you do, 
## change "/dokuwiki" to the path to your dokuwiki directory relative
## to your document root.
#RewriteBase /dokuwiki
#
## If you enable DokuWikis XML-RPC interface, you should consider to
## restrict access to it over HTTPS only! Uncomment the following two
## rules if your server setup allows HTTPS.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^lib/exe/xmlrpc.php$      https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#
#RewriteRule ^_media/(.*)              lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^_detail/(.*)             lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^_export/([^/]+)/(.*)     doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^$                        doku.php  [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
#RewriteRule (.*)                      doku.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php$               doku.php
```

Comment: This is related to your Apache HTTPD configuration.  Two things to check are: /usr/share/dokuwiki/.htaccess file and the <Directory> clause in the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

In the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default i put following:

```
    <Directory /usr/share/dokuwiki/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

If you are migrating from other machine, then you need to copy the `data` folder to /var/lib/dokuwiki/

```
sudo cp -r ~/data /var/lib/dokuwiki/
```

after that i changed only the permissions for the data folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/lib/dokuwiki/data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/dokuwiki/data
```

Now is my dokuwiki working fine.

Comment: Once you've made the changes in the Answer above, remember to do this final step: service apache2 restart Then my dokuwiki started working too. :)